# How can I connect two different views in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Views:

1. `vbsleads.mview_leads`
   list of columns which i want to show

   - `LEADDATE`
   - `LEADSID`
   - `FULLNAME`
   - `ADDRESS`
   - `SOURCENAME`
   - `MOBILEPHONE`
   - `PROBLEM`
   - `LEADASSIGNEDTO`
2. `vbsleads.view_validaccounts`
    list of columns which i want to show

   - `UID`
   - `FIRSTNAME`

I want to show above columns in single mysql query. How do I connect them?

Comment: Where is the relation between the two views? Is there a `UID` stored in the `vbsleads.mview_leads` view?

Comment: There is 'COMPANYID' column which is common between two tables.

Comment: I am fresher in mysql (database) field. please help me if i am wrong anywhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
 SELECT mvl.LEADSID, mvl.LEADSID,mvl.FULLNAME,mvl.ADDRESS,mvl.HOURS_SPENT,
 mvl.SOURCENAME,mvl.MOBILEPHONE,mvl.PROBLEM,mvl.LEADASSIGNEDTO,vv.UID,
 vv.FIRSTNAME
 FROM  vbsleads.mview_leads mvl
 JOIN vbsleads.view_validaccounts vv ON (mvl.COMPANYID=vv.COMPANYID)
```